# Having trouble with awk

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to assign a variable to an awk statement. I am getting an error. Here is the code:

```
for i in `checksums.txt` do
md=`echo $i|awk -F'|' '{print $1}'`
file=`echo $i|awk -F'|' '{print $2}'`
done
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you would display how the actual content of the checksums.txt file looks like. I'm assuming it's `MD|FILE`, but assuming has proven wrong here many times..

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `checksums.txt` do
```

This will try to *execute* `checksums.txt`, which is very probably not what you want. If you want the contents of that file do:

```
for i in $(<checksums.txt) ; do
  md=$(echo $i|awk -F'|' '{print $1}')
  file=$(echo $i|awk -F'|' '{print $2}')
  # ...
done
```

(This is not optimal, and will not do what you want if the file has lines with spaces in them, but at least it should get you started.)

Comment: It doesnt seem that this is working. code in the loop is never run

Comment: how do you know? As is, the code prints nothing. And you didn't specify what error you're having, so I a clueless except for the more obvious problem of you trying to execute a text file.

Comment: after that I tried to echo md and file and nothing came out leading me to believe that the loop is never entered. Perhaps i am missing something.

Comment: What does the checksums file contain? is it in the right directory, with the right permissions?

Comment: I'm sorry you are right, I forgot that I commented out the line that initialized the file. The loop is working fine. At this point I want to use the loop to check for duplicate file types. I changed checksums.txt to dump.txt which is a sorted list of md5sum *space* filename. I need to use the md variable to check which files are duplicates. Since it is sorted the duplicate files will be in a row. However I do not know how to proceed

Comment: That's a completely different question. Please search a bit more, especially the `sort` (and `uniq`) utilities which might very well solve your problem without any loops. If you still want to loop, search for `while read` constructs which will let you read both variables in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need external programs for this:

```
while IFS=\| read m f; do
  printf 'md is %s, filename is %s\n' "$m" "$f"
done < checksums.txt
```

Edited as per new requirement.
Given the file is already sorted, you could use *uniq* (assuming *GNU uniq* and md hash length of 33 characters):

```
uniq -Dw33  checksums.txt
```

If *GNU uniq* is not available, you can use *awk* 
(this version doesn't require a sorted input):

```
awk 'END {
  for (M in m)
    if (m[M] > 1) 
      print M, "==>", f[M]  
  }
{ 
  m[$1]++
  f[$1] = f[$1] ? f[$1] FS $2 : $2
  }' checksums.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
  set -- `echo $line | tr '|' ' '`
  echo md is $1, file is $2
done < checksums.txt
```